# find error for $AX = B$ for many right hand sides

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In order to find error for $AX = B$ for many right hand sides,is the below the right way?

Let's say the product
$$
  AX = \begin{pmatrix}
         1 &2\\
         3 &4\\
         5 &6
       \end{pmatrix} \textrm{ and } B =
       \begin{pmatrix}
         7  &8\\
         9  &10\\
         11 &12
       \end{pmatrix}.
$$

The error is defined as $\sqrt{\sum (B-AX)^2}$

Now,for many right hand sides should I calculate it taking each element of column  $B$ and each of $AX$  or for each row element?

For example , column-wise :

$7-1=6$

$9-3=6$

$11-5=6$

$8-2=6$

$10-4=6$

$12-6$

and then error= $\sqrt{36 * 6}$.

or rowwise:

$7-1=6$

$8-2=6$

and so on.

Comment: How is $\sum(M)^2$ defined? If (curiously enough) it stands for the sum of squares of the elements of $M$, then obviously it does not matter in which order you make the sum due to its associativity.

Comment: @Algebraic Pavel:Hmm..I think you are right.What do you mean how $\sqrt{\sum(M)^2}$ is defined?I am giving it above.

Comment: The Frobenius norm for matrices is the analog of the euclidean norm. It also is connected to a scalar product. If $X$ and $Y$ are matrices of the same format, then $\langle X,\,Y\rangle_F=\text{tr}(XY^T)$. Explore the simplifications obtainable if $A$ is decomposed in QR or SVD factorizations.